# how can I plot a power spectrum for 150 range bins with 512 fft points

Tags: radar

This is my code for plotting... However when I plot my spectrum data using this code, it is showing only 1 row. How can I plot all 150 rows? Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
 for i=1:length(dataheader.nrgb)
   plot(freq,arraydata(i,:)+height(i))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, matlab's `plot` command clears the plot area before drawing the new curve.

To prevent this, and allow multiple curves to appear on the same figure, you can activate the `hold` mode:

```
hold off; % 1st plot will clear figure
for i = 1:length(data header.nrgb)
   plot(freq,arraydata(i,:)+height(I));
   hold on; % set hold mode for subsequent figures
end
```

Alternatively you can stack multiple copies of `freq` and the plot command will draw one curve per column. Since your data is organized by rows, you'll need to transpose your data matrix:

```
% just make sure freq & height are column vectors. This may not be necessary if they already are.
if size(freq,1) < size(freq,2)
   freq = transpose(freq);
end
if size(height,1) < size(height,2)
   height = transpose (height);
end

% plot one curve per column on same figure
N = length(data header.nrgb);
plot(repmat(freq,1,N), transpose (arraydata)+repmat(height,1,N))
```